# Powershell. How to invoke javascript on a web page using AutoBrowse module

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create some automatization using AutoBrowse module.
I now want to click on a web page button which does not have id,name,href etc, just a javascript on click.

I tried a number of combinations but can't figure how exactly -Event switch should be written. There is not a whole lot of examples on the internet either.

Right now I am trying with something like this:

```
Invoke-BrowserControl -IE $ie -Event @{'onclick'='javascript:OnGo()'}
```

Button:

```
<input style="width: 30px; padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 2px; vertical-align: middle;" onclick="javascript:OnGo()" type="button" value="Go"/>
```

Comment: Do you have the URL to share with us, so we can try our side ?

Comment: Sadly, no. Its an intranet resource.  I just don't get any examples of using -Event switch. The description is just poor.

Comment: Have you tried to filter by the type and value ?

Comment: There is no type or value. It's not a control element, just a javascript event on page.

Comment: You could list all elements by tag name, with a tag name "input", then filter with the value property. I'll post an answer soon with an example.

Comment: Get-BrowserControl -IE $ie -TagName input returns nothing or I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24497/discussion-between-agentk-and-ob1lan).

Comment: Where does this cmdlets (Get-BrowserControl and Invoke-BrowserControl) come from ? I never used them, and it's not available on any of my PowerShell versions (I'm running version 4 and 5). Is that a custom function ?

Comment: This is a custom module from Start-Automating team, called Autobrowse. http://autobrowse.start-automating.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using the cmdlets built-in PowerShell, where I'm able to open http://google.fr/fr, then automate the click on a button. Here is the code of the button I'll click from the script :

```
<input value="J'ai de la chance" aria-label="J'ai de la chance" name="btnI" type="submit" jsaction="sf.lck">
```

And here is my script, as an example :

```
$url = "http://google.fr/fr"

$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application

$ie.navigate($url)
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100} 
$ie.visible = $true

$button = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT") | Where-Object {$_.value -eq "J'ai de la chance"}
$button.click()
```

So this script will open IE, navigate to http://google.fr/fr, then click on the "J'ai de la chance" button. So, obviously, you'll have to change the script to filter the 'GO' value.

I hope this will help you to understand how you can achieve your goal !

Comment: Thanks! That's worked! $button=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('input')|?{$_.type -eq 'button'}
$button.click()

Comment: Great, glad that helped. Pay attention your command will work only if there is no more than 1 button on your page. If there are several, you'll have to add another filter to specify which one to click.