# Understanding which HTML tags to consider

Tags: powershell, regex, html

I want extract from my html file some data but I'm little bit confusing because I don't understand what should I consider like tags.
I use this simply code to get data from `<td> </td>` tag

```
$arr = @()
$path = "C:\test.html"
$pattern =  '(?i)<tr[^>]*><td[^>]*>(.*)</td><td>'

Get-Content $path | Foreach {if ([Regex]::IsMatch($_, $pattern)) {
           $arr += [Regex]::Match($_, $pattern)
            }
        }
$arr | Foreach {$_.Value}
```

But data that I want to take have text like this

```
    <td align="center" class="row1"><img src="style_images/1/folder_post_icons/icon11.gif" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td class="row1" valign="middle">
        <div style='float:right'></div>
        <div>
            <a href='http://xxxxxx.org/forum/index.php?showtopic=78777&amp;view=getnewpost'><img src='style_images/1/newpost.gif' border='0'  alt='Goto first unread' title='Goto first unread' hspace=2 /></a> <span id='tid-span-78777'><b><a id="tid-link-78777" href="http://xxxxxx/forum/index.php?showtopic=78777" title="This topic was started: Apr 4 2009, 22:09:22">Evil Blood - The Best Of... &#39;83-&#39;86 [best of/compilation] (1986)</a></b></span>

<script type=text/javascript>
var ch78777=0;var tmr78777=0;
function st78777() {if(!ch78777){my_show_div(my_getbyid(("78777_preview")));getData("act=st&t=78777&view=getpost","78777_preview");tmr78777=-1;}}
</script>
<span
onmouseover='if(!tmr78777) {tmr78777=setTimeout("st78777();",1000);}' 
onmouseout='if(tmr78777) {clearTimeout(tmr78777);};tmr78777=0;if(!ch78777) {my_hide_div(my_getbyid(("78777_preview")));}' 
onmousedown='if(tmr78777!=-1){st78777();};ch78777=1;'
style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="../images/seetopic.gif"></span><div id='78777_preview' class='topicpreview' style='display:none'></div>


            <div class="desc"><span onclick='return span_desc_to_input("78777");' id='tid-desc-78777'>Thrash Metal</span></div>
        </div>
    </td>
```

I try to get 3 text data from 3 different html tags. In my example text are these (you can find them in code above)

```
1. http://xxxxxx/forum/index.php?showtopic=78777
2. Evil Blood - The Best Of... &#39;83-&#39;86 [best of/compilation] (1986)
3. Thrash Metal
```

But I don't understand what tags I need to consider because using DOM inspector I see that for example `id='tid-desc-78777'>TEXT TO EXTRACT</span></div>` have always a different number, for example I can have `id='tid-desc-78777' but also` id='tid-desc-35812'` and so on. Same problem for other HTML tags.

You can see here, for example, names of tags from inspector but in source code why are they different?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofq2E.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should not parse HTML with regex. This Stackoverflow post makes it very clear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

The "proper" way of doing it, short of writing an HTML parser yourself is to use an existing parser and use the results. There is one here for powershell. http://woshub.com/parsing-html-webpages-with-powershell/

The idea is that to fully consume HTML, you need to consider state of parsing, something that regex cannot do.

Even then, when you simply parse response from a web server, javascript will not have been executed so if js modifies the page somehow, you won't get the modifications.

A somewhat easier way to scrape web sites using js is to rely on a browser. This post here describes the very basic to control IE to navigate pages and interact with them. [Powershell. How to invoke javascript on a web page using AutoBrowse module](https://superuser.com/questions/924194/powershell-how-to-invoke-javascript-on-a-web-page-using-autobrowse-module)

The downside is that you'll have an instance of IE opening, but the upside is that you'll have access to the HTML DOM after rendering. This should save you hours of tears and headache

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I see to deepen. Alternatively, are there valid good software (linux or windows) for scraping?

Comment: @Jack Unfortunately, I do not know of any. I usually roll out my own with the technique I just described, python and scrapy library